# Retrieve all PersistentStore keys on blackberry

Tags: blackberry, java-me, mobile, persistent-storage

My application uses the PersistentStore to store data. The keys of the PersistentStore are created at runtime, so there's no way to know all the keys. I'd like to know if there's a way to retrieve or list the persistent store keys used by my application. I want to put them on a ObjectChoiceField and select the one I want to work with.

My application creates a name as a string, and then turns the string into a long value used as a key.  I'm currently thinking to store the names of the PersistentStore on a single RMS, and with it retrieve the keys.   But I would like to keep this option as a last resort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The keys of the PS are created at runtime

You really want to use well-known keys rather than generating them at runtime.    The persistent store is shared across all apps on the device, and I'm not aware of any way to list all the keys.

You could store all the keys as they are generated, which may be what you are suggesting as your last-resort.   You would still need to keep one well-known key, and use that well-known key to store a Vector or array of all the other keys that have been generated.

Comment: I like it!!! I was thinking on using a RMS to store the String values of the keys, but using another PS to stores this seems more logic, and that way i can finally cut ties with RMS, they are a pain in the behind to deal with

I does seems like using runtime generated keys to work with can be something dangerous cuz they are shared between apps, but then again, as i stated, I create in runtime the keys, they need some info extracted from the webservices to be created, so it aint that unsecure, I think.